# What is causing this C# windows service not to start?

Tags: c#, service

It runs fine in debug/console mode, but gets stuck in "Starting" status when started from the Services panel.  It is installed with an installer project, apparently successfully.

The code makes sure a log file is changing every so often.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace FileWatchdogService
{
    public partial class FileWatchdogService : ServiceBase
    {
        private static bool fileChanged = false;

    private int WaitIntervalMs
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinutesTillOverdue"]) * 60 * 1000;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());
                return 15 * 60 * 1000;
            }
        }
    }

    public FileWatchdogService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("FileWatchdog"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "FileWatchdog", "CoreService log watchdog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "FileWatchdog";
        eventLog1.Log = "CoreService log watchdog";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(WatchFile));
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service shut down at " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileWatchdogService service = new FileWatchdogService();

        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            service.OnStart(args);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop program");
            Console.Read();
            service.OnStop();
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(service);
        }

    }

    private void WatchFile(object nothing)
    {
        try
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Initiating watchdog for " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + "  at " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            while (true)
            {
                FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
                watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"]);
                watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"]);
                watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(ProcessChangeEvent);
                watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Changed, WaitIntervalMs);

                if (fileChanged) // Reset the flag for next iteration of the loop
                    fileChanged = false;
                else
                    SendNotificationEmails(); // Watcher timed out
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }

    static void ProcessChangeEvent(object o, FileSystemEventArgs args)
    {
        fileChanged = true;
    }

    private void SendNotificationEmails()
    {
        try
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Timeout of " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinutesTillOverdue"] + " elapsed at " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"]);
            msg.Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSubject"];

            string[] recipients = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailRecipients"].Split(';');

            foreach (string recipient in recipients)
            {
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));
            }

            msg.Body = "File " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + " on " +
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];
            msg.Body += " has not changed in " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinutesTillOverdue"] + " minutes.";
            msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"]);

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Sending emails from " + msg.From + " to " + msg.To + " through server " + client.Host);
            client.Send(msg);
            msg = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Error in SendNotificationEmails: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you checked the event log and are there any other error messages anywhere? It's hard to help when all we get is "Here's my code with no context, you debug it"

Comment: While it's not a direct answer to your question, this might help you diagnose the problem (just insert it at the beginning of service's constructor): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debugger.break

Comment: Is there any possibility that you've turned on the "allow this service to interact with the desktop" option, despite the numerous warnings against doing so?

Comment: Nothing is being recorded in the event log. I'm not seeing any error message whatsoever.

Comment: Debugger.Break(); is not prompting anything

Comment: The option to interact with the desktop is not checked.